# How to generate typings for a library written in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a library written in TypeScript and distributed as a JavaScript bundle. It is used in several apps (JavaScript, CoffeeScript, TypeScript), some of which are pretty old. I want to reference the same piece of code in all of them. That means I need typings for the TypeScript users. Is there a tool to generate typings from TypeScript codebase? Compiler (tsc) doesn't seem to support that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `--declaration` compiler option. It will generate the `d.ts` file(s) for you. It's also available if you are using a `tsconfig.json` file for storing your compiler options.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: compiler options is long list if you don't know exactly what you are looking for ;)